# Least value of $n$ such that $99^n$ begins with a $8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

[image]

MyApproach:

I have to calculate all powers of 99 and see when the number starts with 8.

Solving this step by step

$99^1$=$99$

$99^2$=$9801$

Similarly for others I get n=11

> Is there Any other way I can calculate faster.Please help me if I am wrong?

Comment: Another way to put it is you are trying to solve for the smallest integer $n$ such that $\log_{10}(9)>\{n\log_{10}(99)\}\geq\log_{10}(8)$.

Comment: @Element118 I have not understood.Can you explain in detail Sir.

Answer (score 3):

**Outline, Not Rigorous, No Calculator**

This is not rigorous, but this is what I will do if I were asked such a question in an exam.

We want $(100-1)^n = 100^n - \binom {n}{1} 100^{n-1} + \ldots$.

These are really the terms that contribute to the answer, so definitely $n \lt 10$ is not possible. Even for $n = 10$, we get a number starting with '9' here and the subsequent term is +ve and everything together is going to have a positive effect.

This leaves us with $\color{blue}{n = 11}$ which I have verified as the correct value.

**More Intuition**

We know that $99 \times 99 = 9801$. Now when we further multiply, the essential digits come from $98 \times 99$ which is $9702$ (ignore the 99 at the end). One more multiplication with $99$ and the product will start with $96 \ldots$. This goes on and at $\color{blue}{n = 11}$, we get the value $89\ldots$. (This was essentially explained using the binomial expansion above)

Answer (score 1):

Let's explain how this problem can be made into an easier problem with logarithms.

For $99^n$ to start with the digit $8$, we need $9\times10^x>99^n\geq8\times10^x$.

Taking logs on this inequality gives:

$x+\log_{10}(9)>n\log_{10}(99)\geq x+\log_{10}(8)$

Now we take the integer part:

$\log_{10}(9)>\{n\log_{10}(99)\}\geq\log_{10}(8)$

Comment: The key here is that for a small range of $n$ (say $n<200$), the integer part $\{n \log_{10}(99)\}$ behaves linearly in $n$ because $\log_{10}(99)$ itself is very close to an integer.